# Test for uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Test for uniform continuity the function $ f(x, y) = (x^2 + y^2)^\alpha \sin{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}} $ in $ \{ x^2+y^2 > 1\} $

If we consider $ \alpha < 1 $, then $ \lim_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \to 0}{f(x,y)} = 0 $, so the function has a finite limit, hence is uniformly continuous.

If we consider $ 1 \le \alpha \le \frac{3}{2} $, the partial derivatives will be bounded $ (x^2 + y^2)^{\alpha-1} (2x\alpha \sin{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}} - \cos{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}) $ (and similarly for $y$), and hence the function is uniformly continuous.

If $ \alpha \ge 3 $, $ \exists \epsilon = \frac{3}{4},  \forall \delta > 0: \exists x_1 = y_1 = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\delta} + \delta} $ and $ x_2 = y_2 = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\delta}} $ that $ d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) < \delta $ and $ |f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)| \ge \epsilon$ for sufficiently small $ \delta$. It is easy to check. Hence $f(x,y)$ is not uniformly continuous for $ \alpha \ge 3 $

But I do not know what to do with $ \frac{3}{2} < \alpha < 3 $.